# I can't using VUE js locally

Tags: c#, vue.js

// this is from local it is json object
{
        "Id": 654321,
        "Name": "Mohd",
        "Age": 22
    },
    {
        "Id": 102030,
        "Name": "Fahd",
        "Age": 18
    }
// this is my code not working

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    socialId: '',
    person: ''
  },
  watch: {
    socialId: function() {
      this.person = ''
      if (this.socialId.length == 6) {
        this.lookupsocialId()
      }
    }
    },

  methods: {
    lookupsocialId: _.debounce(function() {
      var app = this
      app.person = "Searching..."
      axios.get('http://localhost:49999/api/people/' + app.socialId)
            .then(function (response) {
              app.person = response.data.Name + ', ' + response.data.Age
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              app.person = "Invalid Zipcode"
            })
    }, 500)
  }
})
```

but I used this is working perfectly
json object {
    "country": "US",
    "state": "NY",
    "city": "SCHENECTADY"
}

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    socialId: '',
    person: ''
  },
  watch: {
    socialId: function() {
      this.person = ''
      if (this.socialId.length == 5) {
        this.lookupsocialId()
      }
    }
    },

  methods: {
    lookupsocialId: _.debounce(function() {
      var app = this
      app.person = "Searching..."
      axios.get('http://ziptasticapi.com/' + app.socialId)
            .then(function (response) {
              app.person = response.data.city
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              app.person = "Invalid Zipcode"
            })
    }, 500)
  }
})
```

Why when I used it locally not working

Comment: Clarify what you are asking. If you are asking why calling `localhost` endpoint isn't working, then debug your local endpoint. Unit test it before going into XHR calls and such.

Comment: Explain what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you need result to json in file, after you using axio response.json(), you can try the following code

```js
<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                title:"Form Register",
                formdata:{},
                message:"",
                success:0,
            }
        },
        methods:{
           register(){
                this.axios.post("http://localhost:8888/form-register",this.formdata).then((response) => {
                       console.log(response);
                       if(response.data.success>0){
                           this.message="You register success";
                           this.success=response.data.success;
                       }
                       else{
                           this.message="Register to failed";
                           this.success=response.data.success;
                       }
                  });
                    
            },
 
        }
    }
 
</script>
```

```html
//construct json
[
  {
    name:"abc"
    age:34
  },
  {
    name:"abc"
    age:34
  }
]
if use php, you can echo json_encode() in php
```